# mysql json field in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, database

I have a JSON field which contains an array of days and times something like

```
{"days": ["Monday", "Tuesday"], "times": ["10:00:00", "11:15:00", "12:30:00"]}
```

I need a query to get all rows with current day and has time between to times
I have tried this query but no luck

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`my_col`->'$.days', '["Monday"]') AND JSON_EXTRACT(`my_col`, "$.times") BETWEEN '12:15:00' AND '12:45:00'
```

And this one also

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`my_col`->'$.days', '["Monday"]') AND JSON_EXTRACT(`my_col`, "$.times") BETWEEN JSON_ARRAY('12:15:00') AND JSON_ARRAY('12:45:00')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what the JSON means and or which results you are after here? i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: As of 8.0.14 (out the previous day), MySQL does not support BETWEEN as a comparison operator for JSON data. You need to re-engineer the query